# How to import Drive API Client Library for Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-drive-api

Quite simply the documentation on how to implement the Google APIs Client Library for Android studio is lacking, to say the least. All the posts i have found on this subject are out-dated, use depreciated values or just plain out don't work. I think it would greatly help if this information was updated for 2015. 
A little information first

1. I'm using Android Studio 1.0.2
2. I'm asking this question because i want to use the Web Drive SDK in my Android app, which has more features than the Google Drive Android, and therefore some information directed more at this area would be appreciated.

So for my question...

**How do I import Drive API Client Library for Java for Android Studio so that I can make the appropriate API calls in my project? i.e what jars do I add as dependencies and how**

Thank you!

---

*If you need examples of how the current documentation is confusing and outdated just ask. I have been researching this topic for the past two days and nothing seems to work, although I'm sure somewhere out there the documentation exists it seems to me that its unreasonable to expect someone new to Google's API Client Library for Java to be able to find it in the current enviroment*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libraries are hosted at:-

- https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client
- https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client
- https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client
- and the auto-generated Drive library at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2

In case you want to include the libraries via gradle, but don't know how to add dependencies to gradle.build, it's something like

```
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0'
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev111-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
```

**NB. THESE ARE NOT THE LATEST VERSIONS, SO CHECK THE GITHUB LINKS ABOVE TO GET THE CURRENT VERSION NUMBERS!!!!**

Comment: While i do appreciate you linking those resources that is NOT what i was asking. I want to know how to import the Google API Library for Java Client(*the last link you supplied*) in my Android Studio project so that i am able to make the API calls in my app.

Comment: it's just a jar file. include it as a dependency just like any third party lib. Is your question about how gradle dependencies work? I've updated the answer to show the extract from build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

That's what i was looking for *pinoyyid*. I knew i had to include the jars as dependencies but i did not know which ones to use. Through some more research i found the jars needed to use the Google Drive API for Java Client. The following lines let me access the API.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-xml:1.19.1'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev155-1.19.0'
```